# Spark Parquet Loader: Reduce number of jobs involved in listing a dataframe's files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm loading parquet data into a dataframe via

```
spark.read.parquet('hdfs:///path/goes/here/...')
```

There are around 50k files in that path due to parquet partitioning.  When I run that command, spark spawns off dozens of small jobs that as a whole take several minutes to complete.  Here's what the jobs look like in the spark UI:

[image]

As you can see, although each job has ~2100 tasks, they execute quickly, in about 2 seconds.  Starting so many 'mini jobs' is inefficient and leads this file listing step to take about 10 minutes (where the clusters resources are mostly idle, and the cluster is mostly dealing with straggling tasks or the overhead of managing jobs/tasks).

**How can I consolidate these tasks into fewer jobs, each with more tasks?**
 Bonus points for a solution that also works in pyspark.

I'm running spark 2.2.1 via pyspark on hadoop 2.8.3.

Comment: I believe you encountered a bug for which a former colleague of mine has filed a ticket and opened a pull request (still without feedback). You can check it out here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21056 If it fits your issue, your best shot is probably voting the issue up and making some noise on the mailing list about it. :)

Comment: does your transformation includes any shuffle .if shuffling involves by default  spark.sql.shuffle.partitions is 200.thats why you are seeing that many tasks for each job

Comment: Can i have an example of what transformations you are doing

Comment: @saipradeepkumarkotha: This issue arises regardless of what subsequent transformations I perform.  This is one of those exceptional cases where spark 'eagerly' performs work---these jobs run even before I perform any action on my DAG.

Comment: @stefanobaghino: I think you've explained what's going on.  It looks like bbossy's discussion suggests that tweaking the `spark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.threshold` parameter might help.  If you write up how tweaking that parameter can solve the problem, I'll accept your answer as the solution (and you'll get the bounty).

Comment: Currently editing my answer.

Comment: Ok, should be done.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you encountered a bug for which a former colleague of mine has filed a ticket and opened a pull request. You can check it out [here](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21056). If it fits your issue, your best shot is probably voting the issue up and making some noise on the mailing list about it.

What you might want to do is tweaking the `spark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.threshold` and `spark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.parallelism` configuration parameters (with the former being cited in the linked ticket) in a way that suits your job.

You can have a look [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/InMemoryFileIndex.scala#L171-L176) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/InMemoryFileIndex.scala#L187-L189) to see how the configuration key is used. I'll share the related snippets here for completeness.

#### `spark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.threshold`

```scala
// Short-circuits parallel listing when serial listing is likely to be faster.
if (paths.size <= sparkSession.sessionState.conf.parallelPartitionDiscoveryThreshold) {
  return paths.map { path =>
    (path, listLeafFiles(path, hadoopConf, filter, Some(sparkSession)))
  }
}
```

#### `spark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.parallelism`

```scala
// Set the number of parallelism to prevent following file listing from generating many tasks
// in case of large #defaultParallelism.
val numParallelism = Math.min(paths.size, parallelPartitionDiscoveryParallelism)
```

The default value for this configuration are `32` for the threshold and `10000` for the parallelism (related code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L584-L601)).

---

In your case, I'd say that probably what you want to do is setting the threshold so that the process is run without spawning parallel jobs.

#### Note

The linked sources are from the latest available tagged release at the time of writing, 2.3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!  I've upvoted the issue and hope others will as well.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions.  Modifying the threshold to be much higher leads to execution blocking on the driver for a long time--maybe then spark tries to discover all files on the driver alone?  I had more luck playing with `spark.sql.sources.parallelPartitionDiscovery.parallelism`.  Strangely, when I set it to 250, it led to lots of jobs (~50), when I set it to 1000 it led to lots of jobs (again ~50), but when I set it to 500 it used fewer jobs (~a dozen) and completed more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Against an object store, even the listing and calls to getFileStatus are pretty expensive, and as this is done during partitioning, can extend the job a lot.

Play with `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.list-status.num-threads` to see if adding more threads speeds things up, say a value of 20-30

Comment: I tried setting that parameter to 25, and it didn't help.  One thing I find strange is that each of these jobs has approx 2100 tasks.  Any idea where that number comes from, and how I could increase the number of tasks per job so that there are fewer jobs?

Comment: You'll have one task per file, minimum, more if the data can be partitioned